# search result combined with pagerfanta

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-4.3, pagerfanta

i have an app, which displays a list of items, in the main page i have add form with two inputs,
the first will contain the month value and the second one will take a year value;
i set up the action inside the controller in that action there is a function that take two arguments "month, year".

```
/**
 * @Route("/bills",defaults={"page": "1"} , name="bills", methods={"GET"})
 * @Route("/bills/page/{page<[1-9]\d*>}", name="bills_paginated", methods="GET")
 * @param BillRepository $billRepository
 * @param Request $request
 * @param int $page
 * @return Response
 */
public function indexBills(BillRepository $billRepository,Request $request, int $page): Response
{
    $formBills = $this->createForm(BillsType::class);
    $formBills->handleRequest($request);
    $getArgs= $request->query->get('bills');
    $Bills =$billRepository->unpaidBills($getArgs,$page);

    return $this->render('homePage/bills.html.twig', [
        'formBills'=>$formBills->createView(),
        'Bills'=> $Bills ,
    ]);
}
```

when i submit the search form, the result is being displayed as its expected, the page pagination is there too, but when i click the next page for example page '2'
and that happens because the `$getArgs` is empty 
is there a way to keep the same arguments while changing the page.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on 'Page 2' you don't send 'year' and 'month' data.

### Solution 1 - inject `bills` form data from controller

I think, the easiest way is to send the `$request->query->get('bills')` to the twig as `formData` for example.
And on your twig add the `'bills' : formData` in the parameters of your route `bills_paginated`

If you do this, symfony will add your form data in your url and you will not lose them when you change your page, so when you do `$getArgs= $request->query->get('bills');` you have your data

### Solution 2 - get `bills` form data from twig

This is easiest solution, get the bills form data directly in twig like this : `{% set formData = app.request.get('bills') %}`.
And on your twig add the `'bills' : formData` in the parameters of your route `bills_paginated`

### Best solution

IMO the best and the cleanest solution is to have a route with the year and month inside like this `"/bills/year/{year<[1-9]\d*>}/month/{month<[1-9]\d*>}/page/{page<[1-9]\d*>}"`

Comment: Yes `{% set params = app.request.get('bills') %}` in the twig will be more easy ;)

Answer (score 0):

i have figure it out myself , Thank you everyone anyone.
so if someone faces the same problem as mine here is how i fixed it :

inside twig the page where the search results is displayed  and at the bottom inside the pagerfanta pagination function i add a `routeParams`.

```
{%
  set params = app.request.get('bills')
%}

{% if Bills.haveToPaginate %}
      <div class="card-footer pagination">
        {{
           pagerfanta(Bills, 'twitter_bootstrap4_translated',
             {
              routeName: 'bills_paginated',
              routeParams:{bills:params}
             })
        }}
      </div>


{% endif %}
```

Now each time i click a specific page the `params` stays the same.

i hope the code is clear enough and helping.